# How to programmatically hide adview in Android?

Tags: android, android-view, visibility

Is there a way to programmatically make the visibility of an adview == false?

e.g. in XML I am able to do this;

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

However, I want to achieve this in Java - I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work;

```
adView.getVisibility().set(false);
adView.setVisibility(false);
adView.setVisibility("invisible");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` if you want to remove it from the layout.

Or `adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` if you just want to hide it.

Comment: Hi, it says I need to wait 18 minutes. I will do though. and I need 15 rating to vote up :(

Answer (score 3):

You should use **View.INVISIBLE**

```
adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: @DannyHilling move ahead . You can use `View.GONE`

Answer (score 2):

> **INVISIBLE**

This will just hide the view.

```
 adview.setVisibity(View.INVISIBLE);
```

> **GONE**

This will completely hide the view from `ParentLayout`

```
 adview.setVisibity(View.GONE);
```